# Move Windows Server 2003 volume to external drive without losing network mapping

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Our main server (Windows Server 2003: Active Directory, domain controller, file server, software repository) has two hard drives installed (maximum). Disk 0 has a primary partition (C:) and an extended partition with two empty, unused logical drives (D: and F:). Disk 1 has a primary partition (E:). The DVD drive is G:.

What I'd like to do is move the contents of E: to an external USB drive connected to the server, delete the extended partition, and make Disk 1 a mirror of Disk 0.

What I want to avoid is anyone who has a map to a folder on the file server from having to remap their shortcuts. I don't think there are a lot of people but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Is this less of a problem than I think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the external drive is formatted NTFS.  If you map the drives using share names, for example, \servername\software, then it is pretty easy.

Stop sharing, move the files, and reshare using the same share name.  The clients won't know the difference.  Make sure NTFS and Share permissions are set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to export the reg key

HKLM|SYSTEM|CurrentControlSet|Services|lanmanserver|Shares

to a file and then edit the paths in the file to reflect the new paths and import the reg key after you've made your changes.

If you need to maintain the NTFS permissions you can use Icacls:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(WS.10).aspx

Comment: The paths are all hex values.  It lists `<share_name>=hex(7):<hex values>`